# Display description while hover on picture

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 12 elements with picture and hidden description. While i hover on pic it displays the description. Than pic and description is in fixed area with some background color but pic from below the description is visible and it's hard to read the description. How can I fully cover pic below while description is displayed ? Let's say pic are 200x200 px so I would like to cover 50px from top of pic.

Here is the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.box').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('.details').show(500);
    $(this).addClass('higlighted');
    $(this).find('.details').css('visibility', 'visible');
  }, function() {
    $(this).find('.details').css('visibility', 'hidden');
    $(this).removeClass('higlighted');
  })
});
```

```css
.products {
  max-width: 1200px !important;
}

.products-description h1 {
  font-family: 'Homenaje', sans-serif;
  font-size: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  padding-top: 2em;
}

.products-description p {
  font-family: 'Mada', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 22px;
  padding-bottom: 3em;
}

.box {
  margin-top: -5em;
}

.box .imgBox {
  padding-top: 2em;
  position: relative;
}

.box .details {
  transition: 0.5s;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.box .details p {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.higlighted {
  background: rgba(98, 192, 23);
  position: absolute;
  transition: 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="row products">
  <div class="col-lg-1 box" id="box">
    <div class="imgBox">
      <img class="product-mouseover" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150

C/O https://placeholder.com/" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="details" id="details">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-1 box">
    <div class="imgBox">
      <img class="product-mouseover" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150

C/O https://placeholder.com/" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="details">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-1 box">
    <div class="imgBox">
      <img class="product-mouseover" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150

C/O https://placeholder.com/" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="details">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-1 box">
    <div class="imgBox">
      <img class="product-mouseover" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150

C/O https://placeholder.com/" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="details">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row products">
  <div class="col-lg-1 box" id="box">
    <div class="imgBox">
      <img class="product-mouseover" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150

C/O https://placeholder.com/" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="details" id="details">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-1 box">
    <div class="imgBox">
      <img class="product-mouseover" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150

C/O https://placeholder.com/" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="details">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-1 box">
    <div class="imgBox">
      <img class="product-mouseover" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150

C/O https://placeholder.com/" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="details">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-1 box">
    <div class="imgBox">
      <img class="product-mouseover" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150

C/O https://placeholder.com/" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="details">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just use the zIndex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only edits needed are in the CSS of .highlighted class & the little JQuery Script.

You can know more about z-index [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp):

```
.higlighted {
  background: rgba(98, 192, 23);
  position: absolute;
  transition: 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

I have used your logic to achieve your need here i.e. by toggling the css visibility class of imgBox.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
  $('.box').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('.details').show(500);
    $(this).addClass('higlighted');
    $(this).find('.details').css('visibility', 'visible');
    $(this).find('.imgBox').css('visibility', 'hidden');
  }, function() {
    $(this).find('.details').css('visibility', 'hidden');
    $(this).find('.imgBox').css('visibility', 'visible');
    $(this).removeClass('higlighted');
  })
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can provide you a solution i've just wrote.

I've not edited your code because snippet seems full of errors, anyway my codes may do what you requested.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    
    .assume-im-img {
      position: absolute;
      width: 150px; height: 150px;
      background-color: #000;
      z-index: 1;
    }

    .assume-im-img:hover {
      cursor: pointer;
      z-index: 3;
    }

    .assume-im-img:nth-of-type(1) {
      top: 0;
    }
    
    .assume-im-img:nth-of-type(2) {
      top: 200px;
    }

    .assume-im-img:nth-of-type(3) {
      top: 400px;
    }

    .im-img-desc-container {
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%; height: 250px;
      background-color: #99ff99;
      z-index: 0;
      visibility: hidden;
    }

    #desc-1 {
      top: 0;
    }

    #desc-2 {
      top: 200px;
    }
    
    #desc-3 {
      top: 400px;
    }

    .desc-shown {
      visibility: visible;
      z-index: 2;
    }

    .im-img-desc {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 2.5%; left: 0;
      width: 100%; height: 50px;
    }

  </style>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function() {
      $(document).on('mouseover', '.assume-im-img', function (e) {
        $('#desc-' + $(this).attr('target')).addClass('desc-shown');
      });

      $(document).on('mouseleave', '.assume-im-img', function (e) {
        $('#desc-' + $(this).attr('target')).removeClass('desc-shown');
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class = "assume-im-img" target = 1>IMG 1</div>
  <div class = "assume-im-img" target = 2>IMG 2</div>
  <div class = "assume-im-img" target = 3>IMG 3</div>
  <div id = "desc-1" class = "im-img-desc-container">
    <p class = "im-img-desc">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
  </div>
  <div id = "desc-2" class = "im-img-desc-container">
    <p class = "im-img-desc">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum is just a simple text placeholder, Enjoy lorem ipsum!</p>
  </div>
  <div id = "desc-3" class = "im-img-desc-container">
    <p class = "im-img-desc">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum very long story and we haven't time to tell it whole.</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```